# Add Public Methods to a Userform Module in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to call a public sub located in a `UserForm` from a `Class Module`?  I want to put a callback in the Form Module but I can't seem to get it to expose.
Is this a fundamental limitation of `UserForms` in VBA?
It is exposed inside the `UserForm` Code Module, I can see it in the intelisense for the `Me` object, but I can't seem to access it from outside the Form Module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The real answer to my question is to have a better understanding of UserForms and since I could not find a good reference for that I thought I would answer my own question to share my learnings.

Thanks to @Dick Kusleika for the key insight!

First of all, this is not a `UserForm`:

[image]

It is no more a Form than a `Class Module` is a variable.
`UserForm1` is a `Class Module` with a GUI and with the following default, inherited properties
[image]

These properties are like a standard `Interface` that is common to all Form `Class Modules` and therefore instances.  The Name property is in parentheses because it is not the name of the object, it is the name of the the `Type` that is used to declare variables to instantiate the particular Form Class.

More properties and methods can be added by the user at design time and this is done in exactly the same way as a Class Module.

For example, in a Form Module...

```
Option Explicit
Dim mName As String
Property Let instName(n As String)
    mName = n
End Property
Property Get instName() As String
    If Len(mName) = 0 Then mName = Me.Name
    instName = mName
End Property
```

In this example, the Form Class Name is used as the default Instance Name.

When you add Controls to the form, its like graphically adding

```
Public WithEvents controlName As MSForms.ControlType
```

...in a Class Module.

The Methods inherited in the standard interface include one called Show.

You can create an instance of a form using `UserForm1.Show` and this is very confusing and misleading.  To me it implies that you are showing the `Object` called `UserForm1` but you are not.  I don't know why you would want to use this method because, apart from being confusing, it does not deliver any direct reference to the object created.  Its a bit like `Dim v as New Type` only worse, because there is no referencing variable.

You can instantiate a Form Class in exactly the same way you can a Custom Class object and *then* use the show method to deploy it...

```
Dim f As UserForm1
    Set f = New UserForm1
    f.Show
```

For me, this is the preferred method.
You can add custom properties and controls to the UserForm1 Class and you can give it a meaningful name when creating it, but you can also reference it using the standard UserForm interface.

For example

```
'In a Class Module
Dim mForm as UserForm1
Property let Form(f as MSForms.UserForm)
    Set mForm = f
End Property
```

For me, after understanding the above, all of my confusion about UserForms and my frustration at not being able to find a decent reference disappears.  I just treat them as Class Modules and its fine.

Comment: Thanks for the illumination. I had been confused about the userform / userForm1 in my project. I'll have to re-read this later and investigate further, but your answer gives me traction in that direction.

Answer (score 6):

The only difference between a Userform and Class Module is that a Userform has a UI element that a Class Module doesn't. So a Userform is just a special type of Class Module.  That means that Public Subs inside a Userform behave just as they do in any other class - as a method of the class.

To access a Public Sub inside a class module (such as a userform), you need to instantiate the class, then call the method.

```
Dim uf1 As UserForm1

Set uf1 = New UserForm1
Uf1.MyPublicSub
```

Comment: That's what I expected, I have an object of type UserForm and I can't do what you say. The object is referencing an active form and Im trying to call the Form Method in a Sub responding to control events exposed inside the Class Module. What is the difference between UserForm and UserForm1 type?

Comment: Ah OK... I think I just got it. Userform1 is the Class. So I need to use that type in the declaration.  I think the left side of my brain just caught up with the right side... I was half thinking of it as a class and half not.

Comment: Yep, you got it. I didn't even think to make that distinction. Userform is a more generic object and you want your specific object, Userform1.

Comment: this has really opened up my eyes and cleared up a lot of confusion around Userforms. The reason I posted this question is because of basic lack of understanding of how they work.  I could not find any decent material on the web and especially not at MS.  For that reason I will sumarise my epiphanies by answering myself...