# Passing Collections from one Userform to another Userform

Tags: excel, vba, collections, userform

I have spent several days trying to determine whether to use arrays or collections to pass multiple variables from one userform to another.  After a few days of experimenting with arrays, I found that collections would perhaps be easier to use.  However, I keep running into errors. For instance, I get a `Variable not defined` error when I use the following code:

```
    Public totalCats As New Collection

    ' then in a private sub
    totalCats.Add(txtTotalCats.Text)

    ' and in a totally different userform, because that's my main goal with this:
    Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
        For i = 1 To totalCats.Item(1)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Am I doing something wrong to get this error?  Also, I get an Error 91 `User-defined type not defined` when I'm not getting that earlier compile error.

Can anyone help me?  I really need to get this to where I can put things in a collection and be able to call it from any userform in the program.  If you need more relevant code, I'll be happy to post it.

**Edit**: fixed partially by Tim Williams comment, now there is a runtime error reading: `Invalid procedure call or argument`

The line of code it points to is:

`With objLbl
    .Caption = Chr(10) & frmCatNames.catNames.Item(i) & " section " & i
End With`

Of course, there's other stuff in the With, but I think the way I called the catNames collection is the problem.

Comment: Here `totalCats` is a public member of the first form, so you need to prefix it with the form name: e.g. `frmFirst.totalCats`

Comment: @TimWilliams  That makes so much sense!  I'll try it.

Comment: Okay, that helped.  Now I have a problem with this line:

`Chr(10) & frmCatNames.catNames.Item(i) & " section " & i`

It's inside a For...Next loop iterating from `i = 1 to frmSheetCreation.totalCats.Item(1)`

It says Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Update your question with that code - hard to read in a comment

Comment: It's impossible to properly monitor the currency of your collection when you declare it with the As New statement (aka auto-instantiation). You cant test to see if its set. It would be a good first step to explicitly instantiate the collection with a Set totalCats = New Collection line as part of your collection management code.

Comment: Is that instead of the `Public totalCats As New Collection`?  Where would I put that?

Comment: Yes, loose the New in the declaration and insert the line I suggested at the point where you want the collection to come into existence, probably just before you load it. Also not a bad idea to make sure that Tools\Options\General Notify before state change is checked. If your form re-compiles at any point - for example if you are dynamically adding controls - the collection will be terminated. There are many possible causes for the behaviour you describe but, to be honest, you haven't left enough code to enable a proper answer.

Comment: Well, I did as you said in your previous comment, and no errors now.  Thanks! You should make that a formal answer so I can approve it and you'll get reputation.  Also, I will do as you just recommended.

Comment: Ok, good. I'll come back with a formal answer later now that I know it worked... Meanwhile, check out the second answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922511/add-public-methods-to-a-userform-module-in-vba    And not a bad idea to tag me with @ in your comments, otherwise I get no notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is originating somewhere else in the code that you haven't included in your question but, there are some general housekeeping issues that I can see and some that may be.

**Declaring Objects with Auto-instantiation**

This is when you include an As New statement in the declaration
    Public totalCats As New Collection
This is generally a bad idea because any reference to the object, including a check to test if it is Nothing, with will cause the object to be initialised.  So you cant test to see if its set before attempting to do something with it. 
Explicitly instantiating the Collection solves this problem

```
Public totalCats As Collection
'Just before you load the Collection...
Set totalCats = New Collection
For Each nextMember in mObject.Members
    With totalCats
        .Add nextMember, nextMember.Name
    End With
Next nextMember
```

Then you can do proper error house-keeping, for example

```
If Not frmCatNames.catNames Is Nothing Then
    With objLbl
        .Caption = Chr(10) & frmCatNames.catNames.Item(i) & " section " & i
    End With
Else
    'Handle error...
End If
```

**Collection Life Cycle In a userForm Object**

A Collection declared inside a userForm Class is set to Nothing very time the module is re-compliled.  For example if a new control is added at run-time.
If you check Tools\Options\General Notify before state loss, then VBE will notify you of this.

**UserForm Object Life Cycle**

Im not sure what frmCatNames is because that code is missing but, it should be an instance of a Form Class that you have created by adding a Form Module in VBE.
You can also auto-instantiate a Form Class. For example if you have a Form Module called UserForm1 then you can invoke an instance of it with

```
UserForm1.Show
```

But its better to explicitly instantiate it like this

```
Dim f As UserForm1
    Set f = New UserForm1
    f.Show
```

The f object will then behave in the way you expect frmCatNames to behave.  I cant tell from your question what that object is but it should be an object that is typed to your Form Class Module and instantiated like that.

There is a little more detail in the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922511/add-public-methods-to-a-userform-module-in-vba)...