# VBA user form closing causes excel to hang

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm having an issue here with a macro causing excel to hang. I've tried several options and searched endlessly. I have 3 forms, but separate. Here's my steps in it:

1. Userform pops up
2. Item from listbox is double clicked in the form.
3. That opens another workbook and runs code on each sheet.

   - (This is done in another function and works perfectly and takes about 15 seconds ending with the focus on the new workbook.)
4. Closes the userform. (This causes it to hang from 7 seconds to 90 seconds depending on the other workbooks size.)

Code below (please excuse the improper format, I had to use my phone... can't login via computer.)

```
Private sub lb_blah_DblClick (Byval Cancel as MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Me.lbl_blah2.caption = "opening aND running"
  'Open and edit xls - Works fine.
  LoadAndFormat me.lb_blah.value

  Me.lbl_blah2.caption = "Ran through format."
  Me.repaint

  '90 seconds with 29 sheets
  'Me.hide
  'Application.enableevents = false '70 seconds

  Unload me '90 seconds - 29 sheets

End Sub
```

Comment: There are a lot of moving parts to this.  Have you confirmed that the code in the other workbooks run flawlessly without the userform in front?  Has it ever run through and completed without hanging?  ie does `LoadAndFormat "workbook Name"` work in a sub flawlessly?

Comment: Yes I have... and it does work flawlessly every single time.
The sketched or rough equivilant of it would be:

'Sub LoadAndFormat (fp as string)'  
'   set s = workbooks.open(fp, false)'  
'   for each mysheet in s.sheets'  
'      mysheet.columns("B:B").insert'   
'   next mysheet'  
'end sub'

Comment: Yes I have... and it does work flawlessly.

Comment: Does excel hang on a consistent file, or is it sporadic?

Comment: It's consistent when it hangs.

Comment: That's a clue, then.  We should explore the file and code it is hanging on.

Comment: see my answer to this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432835/word-userform-wont-open-in-second-currently-active-document-after-opened-unloa/36436624#36436624. What's relevant for you is how to declare and .Show a user form, then unload it. Leave the HIDE in the code you show us. Let the Unload take place when control returns to the calling procedure. See if that approach gives a better result?

Comment: Cindy, thank you for this I have tried your suggestion and had it in my LoadAndFormat function, but that's how I found out about the hangup in the first place. But you reminded me of another option, can I unload every control individually before the hide or unload so it has less to hide?

Comment: It's consistant when it hangs to hide or unload the form.... But when I show one other form it swaps out the forms quickly....

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my computer, and that seemed to fix it. I'm sorry.