# Any issues for making VBA Form events public?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sophisticated UI that processes a spreadsheet etc. and it includes default field values set up from a text file before the form's `Show` method. That's fine if it's processing a sheet and the user simply clicks the `Run` button once. But in some instances, I can send out-of-project calls by setting specific values into the text file and then have the form read them. Since it might involve dozens of sheets to be processed, it would be nice to be able to have the caller issue the `Run` event instead of the user hitting the `Run` button over and over again. But by default, VBA sets a form's events as `Private`. Are there any hidden gotchyas to setting form events as `Public`?

Bottom line is that I can write a line of code to fire the event or I can write a ton using another method to achieve the same result.

Comment: This sounds like an OOP design flaw.  If you have functionality that isn't directly related to the form, it shouldn't be a member of the form.  Put it in some other class or module and then call it ***from*** the form's event handler. If you limit the use of the form to UI, you'll find you'll have much more reusable code.

Comment: @Comintern  Yeah, I have contemplated many a time to rewrite the project as it is butt ugly but it works and I ain't going to go Netscape on it just because. ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922511/add-public-methods-to-a-userform-module-in-vba

Comment: @RobinMackenzie  That reference is not answering my question.

Comment: @Comintern Actually, having an opportunity to review the form's functionality based on your comment, it's all good. The form manages itself and any other non-related functionalities are managed by other modules and classes and passed back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Having changed some of the form's `Private` events to `Public` and having an outside procedure calling them doesn't seem to have any negative impacts (this after almost a week of use).